# can't define command which executes Explore command

Tags: vim, vimrc

I wanted to make an easy way to open a directory. My first try was like this:

```
command! RootDirRubyOpen :e ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247<CR>
```

But it didn't work. "Okay then," I thought. And changed it this way:

```
command! RootDirRubyOpen :Explore ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247<CR>
```

To no effect though. So does anybody know how to make it work and what's wrong with my versions of the command?

P.S. To be frank, the first version was like this: `command! RootDir_Ruby_Open ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but confuse the different syntax for *mappings* and *commands*:

- Commands take *Ex commands*, so the `:` to go from normal mode to command-line mode is not necessary (but doesn't hurt, neither).
- The *Ex command* is executed automatically, don't append a `<CR>`.

So, this should work:

```
command! RootDirRubyOpen Explore ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247
```

The *netrw* plugin intercepts the `:e` of a directory via autocmds; but you can just skip that and use `:Explore` directly.

Of course, this requires that the *netrw* plugin is active and the `:Explore` actually works when typed (which is a good troubleshooting step for commands and mappings).

Comment: Indeed, I mistakenly used syntax for mappings and the trailing `<CR>` made it as if I didn't execute the command. Apparently, `:Explore` works when typed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command works on my box without any issue (`"~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247^M" [New DIRECTORY]`), the second one doesn't seems to. (version 7.2.411).

Remember that if you don't have a .vimrc file, you won't be able to do `:Explore` commands, and also check if you have netrw plugin installed in `:scriptnames` (`/usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim`)

Comment: What has presence of a `.vimrc` to do with ability to execute `:Explore` command? I'm using `vim 7.2`. And `:scriptnames` lists the file you mentioned. To be clear, when you say that the command works for you you mean that `:RootDirRubyOpen` opens corresponding directory?

Comment: Yeah, after using first command, launching `:RootDirRubyOpen` opens that directory as a new one on my box. Answering your question, `.vimrc` file is needed for the `:Explore` commands from my own personal experience, as new installations doesn't seem to use correcty the Explorer without a previous configuration file, even though I might be wrong.

Comment: I moved temporarily all vim files from my home dir and `:Explore .` still opened current directory. So you might be missing something. Also, I couldn't find anything concerning `netrw` in `/etc/vim/vimrc`.